# Is there a cleaner way of getting the last N characters of every line?

Tags: bash, command-line, awk, sed, cut

To simplify the discussion, let `N = 3`.

My current approach to extracting the last three characters of every line in a file or stream is to use `sed` to capture the last three characters in a group and replace the entire line with that group.

```
sed 's/^.*\(.\{3\}\)/\1/'
```

It works but it seems excessively verbose, especially when we compare to a method for getting the *first* three characters in a line.

```
cut -c -3
```

**Is there a cleaner way to extract the last N characters in every line?**

Answer (score 48, accepted):

It's very simple with `grep -o '...$'`:

```
cat /etc/passwd  | grep -o '...$'
ash
/sh
/sh
/sh
ync
/sh
/sh
/sh
```

Or better yer:

```
N=3; grep -o ".\{$N\}$" </etc/passwd
ash
/sh
/sh
/sh
ync
/sh
/sh
```

That way you can adjust your `N` for  whatever value you like.

Comment: This answer works in the general case as well with `egrep -o '.{3}$'`. I'll accept it when the timer is up. :)

Comment: @merlin2011 This will discard lines that have less than 3 characters. If this is the behavior you want, fine, otherwise, you might want to consider `.{1,3}$` instead.

Comment: FYI, ` egrep -o '.{3}$` expects the same character 3 times in a row, so it doesn't generalize to this case

Comment: @Jezzamon no it doesn't, it expects any 3 characters. `egrep` is deprecated in favor of `grep -E` btw.

Answer (score 21):

Why emphasize brevity when it's a tiny command either way? Generality is much more important:

```
$ cat file
123456789
abcdefghijklmn
```

To print 3 characters starting from the 4th character:

```
$ awk '{print substr($0,4,3)}' file
456
def
```

To print 3 characters starting from the 4th-last character:

```
$ awk '{print substr($0,length($0)-3,3)}' file
678
klm
```

To print 3 characters from [around] the middle of each line:

```
$ awk '{print substr($0,(length($0)-3)/2,3)}' file
345
efg
```

Comment: How would one save it to a variable?

Comment: Are you asking 1) how to save the output of the awk command to a shell variable or 2) how to save the substring to an awk variable or 3) something else?

Comment: I was talking about 1. I've found it though...
```f_id="$(echo $filename | awk '{print substr($0,length($0)-5,2)}')"```

Comment: Just a note: `length($0)` is equivalent to just `length`

Comment: Yeah, I know, I just find it clearer to add the 4 extra chars. I could live with `length()` but then you're only saving 2 chars over stating explicitly what you're getting the length of, `$0`, so it doesn't seem a worthwhile tradeoff and I hate `length` as it looks like a variable and variations of that are a pretty common name for a variable (i.e. we frequently have to save the length of some string or array in a variable).

Answer (score 19):

```
rev /path/file | cut -c -3 | rev
```

Comment: I like this answer also because I had almost forgotten about rev. +1! I'll also benchmark both later to see whether double reverse is faster than regex.

Comment: isn't it a bit dummy to replace a single sed 'verbose" by 3 shell command that will use far more ressources ?

Comment: No, it is easier to remember.

Comment: I agree with @NeronLeVelu, this is not a `cleaner` way.

Answer (score 2):

Pure bash solution:

```
$ while read -r in; do echo "${in: -3}"; done
hello
llo
$
```

sed

```
$ sed 's,.*\(.\{3\}\)$,\1,'
hallo
llo
$
```