# I want to use grep to move the last 7 characters of each line to another file

Tags: bash, grep

I have a text file with thousands of lines. The last 7 characters on each line are a mix of letters and numbers (eg AAP8945 or GGR6645). I want to save these in a separate file.

Excuse the noob question, but I can't work it out.

Comment: @oguzismail — you'd need `-o` too, wouldn't you?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. SO is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. The goal is that you add some code of your own to your question to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Comment: If you have GNU sed then @JonathanLeffler has the right answer because it used the tool you asked for.  Do you have the GNU grep or not?  If not then you could use sed: `sed -e 's/^.*\(.......\)$/\1/'`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a cleaner way of getting the last N characters of every line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24427009/is-there-a-cleaner-way-of-getting-the-last-n-characters-of-every-line)

Answer (score 3):

#### With GNU `grep`

Assuming you have GNU `grep`:

```
grep -o -E '.{7}$' input > output
```

The `-o` option means 'output only what matches' (rather than the whole line).  This is the key feature which makes it possible to use `grep` for the job.  Without support for `-o` (or an equivalent option), `grep` is the wrong tool for the job.

The `-E` option is for extended regular expressions, and it means that the `.` (any character) is matched 7 times and then matches the end of line.

#### Without GNU `grep`

If you don't have GNU `grep` (or a compatible `grep` with the `-o` option or equivalent), then you can use `sed` instead (GNU or any other variant):

```
sed -e 's/.*\(.\{7\}\)$/\1/' input > output
```

This matches the start of the line (`.*`) and captures the last 7 characters (`\(…\)`) of the line; it replaces the whole with the captured part, and prints the result.  If your variant of `sed` has extended regular expressions (usually `-E` or sometimes `-r`), then:

```
sed -E -e 's/.*(.{7})$/\1/' input > output
```

The difference is in the number of backslashes needed.

Both of those will print any short lines in their entirety.  If those should be omitted, use:

```
sed -n -e 's/.*\(.\{7\}\)$/\1/p' input > output
sed -n -E -e 's/.*(.{7})$/\1/p' input > output
```

Comment: Or simple BRE - `grep -o '.......$'` (but who likes to count `'.'`)

Comment: One, two, many — or is that too many?  That still requires the `-o` option which is not universal (not being part of POSIX [`grep`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html), AFAIK).

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin you can say `grep -o '.\{7\}$'` with BRE.

Comment: Wow! Thank you. Learning occurred. I didn't think BRE would allow repetition in that manner.

Comment: Again, it depends on the dialect of `grep`, @tshiono.  WIth many versions, you can do as you suggest; with others, you can't. (Checking: POSIX [BRE](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html) does required `\(…\)` to work in BRE — it was not always thus, but POSIX 1997 required support for it.) Probably if the `grep` supports `-o`, it supports the `\{7\}` count notation.  It all gets tricky when it comes to writing portable code.

Comment: On doing some further research (in the rationale for POSIX.2 1992), BRE in POSiX was always defined with `\(…\)` support — but with a note that some historic implementations did not include it.  Unfortunately for me, I learned the BRE notation before POSIX.2, and the support varied back in the days of yore.  These days, it'll be available pretty much everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

```
grep -Eo '.{7}$'
```

Or without grep:

```
rev input|cut -c -7|rev >output
```

The double `rev` is necessary here because I can not specify a position of the text from the right with `cut`.